# CodeIgniter pass variables form controller to model

Tags: codeigniter

Ok I want to pass two variables from a controller to a model but I get some kind of error. Am I passing variables on right way? My syntax is:

Controller:

```
public function add_tag(){

            if(isset($_POST['id_slike']) && isset($_POST['id_taga'])){

                    $slika = $_POST['id_slike'];
                    $tag = $_POST['id_taga'];

                    $this->load->model("Member_model");
                    $res = $this->Member_model->add_tags($slike, $tag);

               foreach ($res->result() as $r){

                echo $r->name;
                        }
                 }
                  else{

                     echo "";
                  }
    }
```

Model:

```
 public function add_tags(){

            $data = array(
               'tags_id' => $tag ,
               'photos_id' => $slika

    ); 

        $check = $this->db->query("SELECT tags_id,photos_id FROM bridge WHERE bridge.tags_id='{$tag}' AND bridge.photos_id={$slika} ");
        if($check->num_rows()==0){

             $this->db->insert('bridge',$data);
    $res = $this->db->query("SELECT name  FROM tags where `tags`.`id`='{$tag}'  ");
    return $res;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing variables correctly, but do not get them correctly in the model, which should look like this:

```
public function add_tags($slike, $tag){
   //your other code
}
```

Comment: tnx i try on that way before, proabably some typo

Comment: But can i get also results form controler in same line? $res = $this->Member_model->add_tags($slike, $tag);

               foreach ($res->result() as $r){

                echo $r->name;
                        }
                 }
                  else{

                     echo "";
                  }
    }

Answer (score 0):

The following code write on the controller file:-

`$data = array();
$this->load->model('dbmodel');
$data['item'] = $this->dbmodel->getData('*','catagory',array('cat_id'=>21));
$this->load->view('listing_view', $data);`

The following code write on the dbmodel file:-

```
 public function getData($cols, $table, $where=array()){
 $this->db->select($cols);
 $this->db->from($table);
 $this->db->where($where);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 $result = $query->result();

 return $result;}
```